# Exclude page from WordPress Processing

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I have a main site with multiple pages managed by WordPress. I also have a custom developed page on a different path, which is required by Google Auth as a callback. This page contains custom JS and works fine most cases. The callback by Google adds a whole plethora of parameters outside of our control, such as this example: [image: Google callback URL]

```
https://<mydomain>
          / Home page managed by WP
          /-- Sub pages managed by WP
          /scheduler/googleCalendarRegistration.html <== custom page NOT managed by WP
```

In some cases WordPress interfers and throws a "404 - Not found error", when the custom page is called.

I need help either editing .htaccess or installing a plugin, so that my custom page is not funneled through the WP engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like the following at the very top of the root `.htaccess` file to prevent any further processing (including routing the URL through WordPress) when the stated URL-path is requested:

```
RewriteRule ^/?scheduler/googleCalendarRegistration\.html$ - [END]
```

This does not check the query string (so any query string is permitted).